# Find the Useless Edges in a Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am having a graph having `N` components which are connected together , I have to find the number of edges that are useless.
A edge is said to be useless if we remove that edge , whole graph is still connected.
**My Approach**
Run DFS and count the number of visited nodes more than once.

```
public static void search_me(int  i , int pa){

        V[i]=true;
        for(int j:maps[i]){


               if(!V[j]){
                 search_me(j,i);

               }else if(pa!=j){ 
                   useless++;
               }

        }

}
```

But it's not giving me correct answer. What a right approach to do it ?

Comment: "Run DFS and count the number of visited nodes more than once." - well, what makes you so sure it's the *correct* solution? running dfs/bfs from a single node gives you only one representation of a graph... The problem is much easier, hint: what is the minimum number of edges you *need* in order to have a graph with `n` nodes connected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Tarjan's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)#Tarjan.27s_Bridge-finding_algorithm) algorithm to find all bridges within each component in O(n). Bridge is an edge which its deletion makes the graph disconnected.
Then the number you want will follow: number of edges of the graph - number of bridges.

Answer (score -1):

If the graph initially is connected, it posesses a spanning tree, which has exactly `n-1` edges where `n` is the number of vertices; this phenomenon is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454639/how-many-edges-does-an-undirected-tree-with-n-nodes-have). Hence, if the initial graph has `m` edges, the number of useless edges is `m - ( n - 1 ) = m - n + 1`, which can be directly determined without a graph algorithm.

Comment: This is wrong. Consider a cycle of length 100. All of its edges are useless by OPs definition. You count only one of them.